# service on different namespace

Tags: python3, service, namespace, call-service, node

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey guys

Quick question: I was wondering if it's possible to call services that are created on nodes with different namespaces? For instance, if I have node_1 on namespace node_1, can I call service_2 from node_2 with namespace node_2?

I am using ROS Noetic with Python 3.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/353591/service-on-different-namespace/) by [anonymous53443](https://answers.ros.org/users/53443/anonymous53443/) on ROS Answers with karma: 63 on 2020-05-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes, why wouldn't you be able to do that?

In the end, all namespaces do is prefix regular names with more characters.

As a service identifier [is just a name](http://wiki.ros.org/Names), it doesn't matter whether there is a prefix prefixed or not.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2020-05-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [anonymous53443](https://answers.ros.org/users/53443/anonymous53443/) on 2020-05-31**:
thank you.